# Rails 3.2.21 and Ruby 2.2.0 breaking Time.zone.parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

With Rails 3.2.21 and Ruby 2.2.0p0 the time zone parser is broken. With Ruby 2.1.2 this was working just fine.

```
[1] pry(main)> Time.zone.parse("2015-01-12")
NoMethodError: undefined method `year' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:275:in `parse'
```

Now I know that you can replace it with `Time.parse("2015-01-12").localtime` but this breaks functionality in my apps. Are there any known fixes for this?

Comment: Complicating matters: ruby 2.1.5 and 2.2 don't even have a `Time.zone()` method.  There is a `zone()` instance method, and the source code for that did change between ruby 2.1.5 and 2.2.  It's some indecipherable C code, though.  I don't have any idea whether rails uses ruby's #zone method inside of its Time.zone() method.

Comment: I was digging through the activesupport source code and it seems like the line `def parse(str, now=now)` which worked in 2.1.2 now has the rightside `now` evaluate to be nil on 2.2.0. In the latest master branch of activesupport its now more specific to be `def parse(str, now=now())` but this seems like a major, breaking change.

Comment: Okay, good sleuthing.  See my answer for what you can do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR: rails bug that has been fixed, first fixed version on the 3.2 branch is 3.2.22

Ruby 2.2 changes how default arguments are resolved when there is a name ambiguity:

```
def now
  ...
end

def foo(now = now)
end
```

In older versions of ruby calling `foo` with no arguments results in the argument `now` Being set to whatever the `now()` method calls. In ruby 2.2 it would instead be set to nil (and you  get a warning about a circular reference)

You can resolve the ambiguity by doing either

```
def foo(now = now())
end
```

Or

```
def foo(something = now)
end
```

(And obviously changing uses of that argument)

Apparently the way it used to work was a bug all along. Rails had a few places where this bad behaviour was relied on, including in AS::Timezone.parse. The fix was [backported](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3a30b12c774dfaa72acfe520e823374131631ea9) to the 3-2-stable branch and eventually released as part of 3.2.22.

The commit to rails [master](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e88da370f190cabd1e9750c5b3531735950ab415) fixing the issue has a link to the ruby bug filed about this

Comment: As of Rails 3.2.22 that commit is now published: https://github.com/rails/rails/commits/v3.2.22

Answer (score 2):

So, this was your original situation:

```
class Dog

  def do_stuff(x, y=2)
     puts x + y
  end

end


d = Dog.new
d.do_stuff(1)

--output:--
3
```

But, the code for do_stuff() has changed, and now you are faced with something similar to this:

```
class Dog

  def do_stuff(x, y=nil)
     puts x + y
  end

end


d = Dog.new
d.do_stuff(1)


--output:--
1.rb:4:in `+': nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
    from 1.rb:4:in `do_stuff'
    from 1.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

Blasted !@#$!@#$!@#$!@#$!@#@# developers!!!

In ruby, you can use `alias_method()` to create an additional name for a method:

```
class Dog  #Reopen the previously defined Dog class.
  alias_method :orig_do_stuff, :do_stuff  #Create additional name for do_stuff()

  #Now redefine do_stuff():
  def do_stuff(x, y=2)  #Use a better default value for y.
    orig_do_stuff(x, y) #Call the original method.
  end
end

d.do_stuff(1)


--output:--
3
```

According to the rails docs, [Time.zone()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-zone) returns a [TimeZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) object, so that's the class that defines `parse()`, which is the method you want to alias.  So, the code would look like this:

```
class Timezone  #Re-open the Timezone class.
  alias_method :orig_parse, :parse  #Create an additional name for parse().

  def parse(str, now=now())  #Now, redefine parse().
    orig_parse(str, now)     #Call the original parse() method.
  end
end
```

Then, you can call parse() like you always have:

```
Time.zone.parse("2015-01-12")
```

I guess you should put the code inside `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`.  See if that works.

I think the above would be considered an `Adapter pattern`.  Although, because the *plug* already fits--it just does't produce the results you want--it might be considered a `Decorator pattern`.  So, now you can put on your resume that you use custom Adapter and/or Decorator patterns in your rails code. :)

Comment: upvoted because you described a nice workaround which I believe should be used when there is no fix available (unlik the stable 3.2 branch in this case)

Answer (score 2):

Extending [7stud's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28131917/2621588) answer, since `parse` method is defined in ActiveSupport::TimeZone class, you can simply open it and make this slight change accordingly.

You may place this under `config/initializers/timezone.rb` or refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766173/where-to-reopen-a-class-in-ror) for alternative places to pace this.

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeZone
  alias_method :orig_parse, :parse  #Create an additional name for parse().

  def parse(str, now=now())  #Now, redefine parse().
    orig_parse(str, now)     #Call the original parse() method.
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a practical solution if you're on a version of rails for which it's not clear if the fix has been backported (4.1 in my case).